# Xamarin Android ListView - Delete button fires multiple times

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Set up a customer adapter for a list view that I'll need to be able to delete from.  The GetView looks like this, including the code for my view holder as well

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var row = convertView;
        IngredientHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null)
        {
            row = _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.EditableIngredientListViewItem, null);
            holder = new IngredientHolder
            {
                IngredientName = row.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editableIngredientNameTextView),
                Measurement = row.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.measurement),
                DeleteButton = row.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.delete_ingredient)
            };

            row.Tag = holder;
        }
        else
        {
            holder = row.Tag as IngredientHolder;
        }

        var ingredient = IngredientList[position];
        holder.Measurement.Text = ingredient.Measurement;
        holder.IngredientName.Text = ingredient.Name;
        holder.DeleteButton.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
            IngredientList.RemoveAt(position);
            NotifyDataSetChanged();
        };

        return row;
    }

    private class IngredientHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public TextView IngredientName { get; set; }
        public TextView Measurement { get; set; }
        public ImageButton DeleteButton { get; set; }
    }
```

The problem is though, that when I click a delete button it fires many times with different positions eventually getting to a point where I've removed items from the list and the value of position is out of range and I get an exception.

What is the proper way to delete and remove items from a listview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace code with below code,so that it will not call many time.

```
if (! holder.DeleteButton.HasOnClickListeners)
{
 holder.DeleteButton.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
            IngredientList.RemoveAt(holder.AdapterPosition);
            NotifyDataSetChanged();
        };

}
```